# div skipping overflow hidden but remaining relative to parent div

Tags: html, css

First of all here you have a codepen with the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPPjYp

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="blabla span6">  
      asdfasdf<br>
      <span>asdfas</span>
      <div class="bleble"></div><br>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="child"><div class="blibli">aabasdg</div></div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper { position:relative; width:1280px; }
.parent { position:absolute; }
.child { position:fixed; width:960px; }
.blabla {
   overflow:hidden;
   background-color: red;
   height: 90px;
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   position: relative;
 }
.bleble{
   height: 10px;
   width: 90px;
   background-color: blue;
 }

 .blibli{
   height: 150px;
   width: 60px;
   background-color: orange;
 }

 body {
   height: 900px;
   background-color: lightgreen;  
 }
```

In that codepen you will see:

- body of the document (green)
- li element (red) with CSS overflow hidden
- some content inside the li element (some words and a blue div)
- a special div which does not care about the overflow hidden of the "li" (orange)

As it can be seen on the example when you scroll down the body of the page the orange div remains in the same fixed position outside of the overflow hidden "li" element.

What I would like to happen is that the orange box remains out of the overflow hidden (as it is now) but in a relative position of the parent element (in that cas the "li"), so when you scroll down it remains not on a fixed position in the page but on a relative position to the parent.

I would like to emphasize the fact that it should skip the overflow hidden of the parent... this is a condition which could not be changed...

And if possible without javascript and using only CSS...

Do any of you know if this is actually possible?

Comment: it is in the real code, I just created a fast example by copying a bunch of my code into the codepen and editing it to check it out how to perform what I ask

Comment: I have just edited so it accomplishes what you have said, any idea about my question?

Comment: What do you mean by relative position of parent?

Comment: in the codepen I have linked on my question I mean by "relative position of parent" what would happen if you scroll down on the body and the "orange box" remains in the same distance and position to the father.

Comment: `.child { position:fixed;` - that’s what causes the problem.

Comment: Now when you scroll down, as the orange box is fixed, it remains in the same position on the page but increases/decreases distance to the father

Comment: Yes @CBroe, I know this is what causes the problem, but how can I modify it so it behaves as I would like to?

Comment: If I remove the     position:fixed;      then it is hidden by the overflow:hidden

Comment: I don’t understand how you want it to behave.

Comment: I want it to skip the overflow hidden of the parent "li" but not to be fixed on the page, so when you scroll down it keeps the distance with the parent "li"

Comment: @Ignasi not possible. But why do you need the `overflow:hidden` on that element ?

Comment: it's mandatory for the app I am doing. there will be some text which will need to be ellipsed and thus I need to have overflow:hidden...

Comment: Question already answered by @ovokuro. It seems it was possible at the end! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Removing `position: relative` from `.blabla`
2. Setting `position: absolute` on `.wrapper`, `.parent` and `.child`.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1280px;
}
.parent {
  position: absolute;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 960px;
}
.blabla {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.bleble {
  height: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.blibli {
  height: 150px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: orange;
}
body {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="blabla span6">
      asdfasdf
      <br>
      <span>asdfas</span>
      <div class="bleble"></div>
      <br>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="parent">
          <div class="child">
            <div class="blibli">aabasdg</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/vggwgE)

Comment: Thank you very much @ovokuro! I will check it out now if it works on my app and mark this question as the answer in case it works as expected!

Comment: I confirm it works exactly as I expected it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.wrapper {  
  width:1280px; 
}

.child { 
  position:absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 20px);
  width:960px; 
}

.blabla {
  background-color: red;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.bleble{
  height: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.blibli{
  height: 150px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: orange;
}

body {
  height: 900px;
  background-color: lightgreen;

}
```